# AppCompat Actionbar styling

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

I'm currently trying to use AppCompat instead of ActionbarSherlock. On Android 4+ devices I don't run into any problems, as the normal Actionbar and Holo theme are used.

[image: ICS Actionbar]

On lower Android versions however, this weird look happens when using Theme.AppCompat.Light.

[image: Standard AppCompat Actionbar]

The Actionbar is white and has a blue line underneath.

I was able to fix that by using the [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) from Android Asset Studio to generate a custom theme with a solid Actionbar instead of the transparent one.

[image: AppCompat with custom drawables from Style Generator]

When comparing it to the Actionbar I got when using ActionbarSherlock, it's still kind of ugly though.

[image: ActionbarSherlock]

The AppCompat Actionbar has this very sharp, black line between itself and the content of the activity, while the stock Actionbar of ICS or the one of ActionbarSherlock have a softer transition from the Actionbar to the layout.

How can I style the Actionbar to really look like the one on Android 4+?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to create your own style with the image you want to put on background. In your style.xml, you should create something similar to this:

**values/styles.xml**

```
    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.MyAppTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="background">@drawable/your_background_image</item>
    </style>
```

**values-v14/styles.xml**

```
    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.MyAppTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_background_image</item>
    </style>
```

and you can use this 9-patch image :

[image: 9-patch image]

Comment: Thanks, now I know where to go.

Comment: in addition, overriding background with custom drawable is unnecessary. Override **actionBarStyle** from **Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid** is enough.

Comment: Also, you can use displayOptions tag to centralize the ActionBar display options <item name="displayOptions">showTitle|homeAsUp</item>

Answer (score 3):

I use this code:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/red_action_bar</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I hope this code is of great help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the theme of the action bar

Answer (score 0):

To show custom icon & color in **AppCompatActivity** we can paste this code:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>

 <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyAppTheme</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**values-v14/styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyAppTheme</item>
       <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/app_titile_bar_color</item>
</style>
```

You can use your custom background picture as well from @drawable/your_pic.png

To show app icon & Text you also paste this to your activity.

```
        // set action Bar icon & Text
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```