# Remove shadow below ActionBar without Sherlock

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am using AppCompat for compatibility instead of Sherlock. Is there any way to remove the shadow below the ActionBar? I have searched for so many answers and all rely on Sherlock, which means, that

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

does simply not work with AppCompat.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Sherlock uses the default `ActionBar` if the system version of the device is above `14`.

If you generate a theme for your actionbar using this [tool](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) you will have background `9patch` images for your actionbar. If you look at them closely you will see a different color at the bottom which causes this shadow look. Just remove it using a photo tool and you will get a shadow free theme for your `ActionBar`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the appcompat-v7 resources library /res/style_base.xml:

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar.Solid" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/abc_ab_solid_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/abc_ab_stacked_solid_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.ActionBar.Solid"
       parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/abc_ab_solid_light_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/abc_ab_stacked_solid_light_holo</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo</item>
</style>
```

And I also found this answer:

[AppCompat Actionbar styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464452/appcompat-actionbar-styling)

So IMO, what you want to do is to re-style the ActionBar theme (as in the answer) and give it your own drawable that doesn't have a shadow.

Edit: I find this answer is more closer to your question:

[Strange divider with the v7 support actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737419/strange-divider-with-the-v7-support-actionbar)

So sorry I could not have more research on how those attributes acts in the effect.

Answer (score 0):

This works with AppCompat:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```